# View your source map files produced using webpack

Tags: javascript, django, webpack, source-maps, django-compressor

My application uses django on the backend and Vuejs on the frontend (doesn't use vue-cli). So the `index.js` from Vue is used something like this in my `base.html`

```
{% compress js %}
  <script type="module" src="{% static 'path/to/index.js' %}"></script>
{% endcompress %}
```

**Producing this** -> `index.4b6f970ead9c.js` -> A compressed file in `static/CACHE/js`

I need to build source-maps as `.map` files which in the end will be uploaded to sentry.

Following is in my `webpack.config.js` :

```
devtool: 'source-map',
output: {
  sourceMapFilename: '[file].map',
}
```

Doing this, I get a warning on my console :

```
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for http://localhost:8000/static/CACHE/js/tmpy_nqoqkg.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE
```

I should expect the `.map` file to be in `static/CACHE/js` right? I couldn't any file with a `.map` extension anywhere in my app.

But in the end of this (`index.4b6f970ead9c.js`) compressed file that is loaded I do see a mapping : `//# sourceMappingURL=tmpy_nqoqkg.js.map`

Is there any way I can physically save the `.map` file for my application and use it later?

Comment: are you using awesome-typescript-loader?

Comment: nope using JavaScript, with babel-loader

Comment: Try defining output.path and output.publicPath to static/CACHE/js

Comment: Tried doing that, also tried using `path.join(__dirname, 'static/CACHE/js')`  doesn't work